# Have an Android HTML5 app listen for intents

Tags: android, html, android-intent

I am developing an app that is used by just a couple of people at my work.  It's an easier way for them to handle support cases that they get while off-hours.  I've created an HTML5 site and made it so that it can be launched fullscreen from their Android phones by using the "Add to Home screen" option within Chrome.  That works great.  Now, I want to make it so that when they get an email notifying them of an incoming support case, they can click the link for the case and open **the app** instead of it opening in a regular web browser.  Otherwise, the usefulness of fullscreen is lost.

Unfortunately, I just don't know how to do it.  Every search I make regarding this brings up information on Intents, but all my searching on intents assumes that I'm developing an Android-native application, not an HTML5 app.  Is it possible for apps that are created via the "Add to Home screen" option to listen for intents?  If so, where do I begin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No that is definitely not possible**, you will need an Android application which uses an `Activity` class otherwise you won't be able to listen to react on intents or listen to broadcast receivers... 
But you can create a simple application holding a `WebView` which loads your HTML content. Then you will have the ability to use Intents and Broadcast-Receivers and pass on received information to your HTML content.